# Is it possible to get the first image of a location from Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to add some decoration to a project for a university exam.

In particular, for a given place/location I'd like to provide a image for reference.

I see that it is possible to get a static map image from google maps:

```
String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap? [...]";
```

and this is already useful for me.

What I'd like to achieve is to get the first image from the Google Maps page, for example, if I search "tour eiffel" the first image I get is this:
[Tour Eiffel image from Google Maps](https://www.google.it/maps/place/Torre+Eiffel/@48.8598133,2.3284027,3a,75y,90t/data=!3m8!1e2!3m6!1s-tWg5dUMgEg4%2FWC_h7Ip7RwI%2FAAAAAAAAg78%2FwoOJMzYwobsZZrTeaOCUiZheV1Z-TDLwQCLIB!2e4!3e12!6s%2F%2Flh3.googleusercontent.com%2F-tWg5dUMgEg4%2FWC_h7Ip7RwI%2FAAAAAAAAg78%2FwoOJMzYwobsZZrTeaOCUiZheV1Z-TDLwQCLIB%2Fs114-k-no%2F!7i1234!8i926!4m5!3m4!1s0x47e66e2964e34e2d:0x8ddca9ee380ef7e0!8m2!3d48.8583701!4d2.2944813!6m1!1e1)

Please note that this is not the same as searching "tour eiffel" on Google Image, this is a different kind of query I guess.

-knowing that probably most/all of the photos provided are subjects to copyright, but cleared that this is just for an exam, is it possible to get a image from a Google Maps place?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [Google Street View Image API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/?hl=de). I think it does exactly what you need.